# Is there a way to read disk access times in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to read disk access times in python? There is numerous scripts I've found in c/c++. Just wondering if there's one for pure python or cython. Looking for similar functionality to WHDD or MHDD.

Comment: i think this link will be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292071/disk-seek-time-measurement-method

Comment: Looks like its linux only, know of one for windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for windows you can right click the bar on the bottom of your screen, choose joblist -> (tab) peformance -> Disc, here you will find basic data of the disc IE response time, at the bottom there's also a link called "recource survailence" mine is in danish so sorry if the translation is wrong there, in there will be a bit more data.

**UPDATE**

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from time import time

starttime = time()
Dispatch('Scripting.FileSystemObject')
endtime = time() - starttime

print(endtime)
```

this is the only way i can come up with to find out, and i don't know how to do it sector by sector

Comment: Ok. But is that a sector by sector scan? Also this is for a future software suite I'm planning on developing. Need the results from it in code somehow